# Who is the 'king of Assyria' referred to in Ezra 6:22?

Tags: ezra

EDIT NOTE: This question has not been satisfactorily answered previously.

Neither :

- Fleishman's 'literary didactic ploy'
- nor Williamson's 'no fully satisfactory explanation'
- nor Blenkinsop's 'scribal error' (unevidenced) / 'could simply stand for Mesopotamia'

can be seriously regarded as 'answers' to this question. So I am hoping for a sensible answer to be forthcoming . . .

---

In Ezra 6:14 there are three kings mentioned :

> And they builded and finished according to the commandment of the God of Israel and according to the commandment of Cyrus and Darius and Artaxerxes, king of Persia.

All three of these kings were kings of Persia, but in verse 22, the narrative states :

> The Lord had made [the children of Israel] joyful and turned the heart of the king of Assyria unto them.

Who is this 'king of Assyria' ?

Comment: I have given some of my reasonings in other responses as to why I believe the Assyrian is referencing a spiritual being, namely satan so I won’t repeat this over and over. And now you take this text and given the Assyrian empire no longer existed by the time this prophecy was being fulfilled only the Assyrian culture I think I have a good case together with many other passages to conclude that the Assyrian is satan or the spirit of antichrist

Comment: Darius was king over more than just Persia as the question may imply, since his father Ahasuerus reigned over much(Ester 1:1-3); in the least this included Persia and Media. In any case, Darius reigned over Chaldea(Daniel 9:1).

Comment: @user21676 Your comment appreciated. Thank you.